# Pycharm Python console wont show documentation in code completion pop up

Tags: python, pycharm, console

When i write code in Pycharm the code completion shows a drop down with suggestions and also a documentation of the suggested class or whatever, pops up with information about the element. In this case bar method, see Picture 1:

[image: documentation pop up filled with information]

In the Python console you can do the same but i get an empty documenation pop up, see picture 2:

[image: Empty documentation pop up in python console]

In the example the debug mode is running and is halted at the breakpoint in picture 1.

Any suggestions how this popup can reach the informations of the documentation? Maybe it got something to do with the dir() method.